# Accessing a shared USB printer outside the domain?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, domain, printer, share

I have a setup with a Windows XP Professional computer joined to a domain. This computer has a USB printer installed, which is in turn shared. I can use this printer from other computers fine, as long as they are in the same domain. I cannot however add this printer on a computer outside the domain. It get's found when browsing, but won't add. Is this something that is possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add a local user account (or accounts) to the workstation and grant them permissions to use this printer.

Answer (score 0):

Is File and Print sharing enabled on the non-domain machine?

Can you see the printer by opening up Windows Explorer and typing \\computername into the address bar.  If so, right-click on the printer and select 'connect.'